# Disable interaction on UIWebView, only link clickable?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, ios6.0

i am adding UIWebview in tableview for showing text and link , but not able to scroll tableview, Any way to disable user interaction in webview only click event enable.

Webview have static content not load from web

```
NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script> document.ontouchmove = function(event) { if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) event.preventDefault(); } </script><style type='text/css'>* { margin:0; padding:0;} p { color:white; font-family:HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold; font-size:24px;} a { color:#63B604; text-decoration:underline; }</style></head><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", @"search in http://google.com"];
```

Thanks

Comment: `[webview.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

just disable scrolling or using this methods

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Disable user selection
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];
    // Disable callout
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

and open link as follow using delagate methods

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        NSURL *url = [inRequest URL];
        if ([[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"gmail"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: your html is not a proper formet

Comment: i just need to show text with link so using webview, my ui structure is scrollview for vertical paging and each page add tableview in one of table view cell have text with link achive text with link by webview,but in webview i am not able to scroll a scrollview ,this is a problem

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable scrolling in your WebView

```
[myWebView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO]; 
[myWebView.scrollView setBounces:NO];
```